# Lightroom: Folder display doesn't match filesystem

Tags: lightroom, file-management

I recently imported my iPhoto library into Lightroom using Lightroom's import facility.

The result of that was a neatly arranged filesystem, like thus:

```
2012/
  01/
    2012-01-03/
      ... files
    2012-01-10/
      ... files
2014/
  05/
    2014-05-13/
      ... files
    2014-05-21/
      ... files
```

However.. in the Folders/Macintosh HD panel inside Lightroom, what I see is this:

```
2012-01-03/
2012-01-10/
... etc ... many more years of photos
2014/
  05/
    2014-05-13/
    2014-05-21/
```

I don't know why 2014 is being treated differently from all previous years. It is not different in the filesystem. I have a lot of photos so this makes the list really long and unwieldy. I would like to have the top-level folders appear as they do in the filesystem, where the top-level is the year.

Any insight into why this happened and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm going from memory here.)

Lightroom for Windows let's you "Show Parent Folder" by right-clicking a folder in Lightroom's hard drive pane.  By showing enough of the parent folders you should see a structure that matches your hard drive folder structure.